# Cannot make windows fullscreen in Loki with multiple monitors

Tags: display

I have a 3-monitor setup using 2 external monitors in addition to the primary display on my monitor. I have the external monitors side by side, with the primary laptop display centered below them. When I try to make anything full-screen in the external monitors they appear to only expand to the top left or right corner of the primary display instead of spanning the entire screen. Below is a screenshot with my current setup, as well as a "fullscreen" Opera window.

[image]

Comment: How did you fix this problem? This is if you were able to

Comment: Sadly, I did not. My solution to this after posting here, in the Elementary forums as well as in the Elementary IRC channel was to move to a distro that had better community support.